# Windows azure and Mapreduce

Tags: azure, hadoop, mapreduce

I trying to design an architecture on windows azure like the one described in the customer scenario paragraph of this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697709.aspx .

I can't however figure out why this solution is described as map-reduce design pattern?
Is there any connection between this architecture and mapreduce?
Do you have any ideas?
Also as I am searching I found that azure provides the ability to use hadoop.

Comment: This is completely wrong. The architecture they propose is a `reduce-all` pattern (distributing work, combining the result on a single instance). Dispite that all of those distributed patterns are actually linked to each other, this is certainly not mapreduce.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut thanks for your response. Is there a link for the reduce-all pattern you are referring?  Also what do you mean with the "those distributed patterns are actually linked"?